# svg.draggable.js svg.js - object move to the left on click

Tags: javascript, svg.js

With the svg.draggable.js

On firefox/safari, When you click in the text it move to the left a bit.

Follow the code https://jsfiddle.net/gnmobz34/4/

```
var draw = SVG('draw').size(400, 400)   
var text = draw.text("Some string")

text.font({
    family:   'Helvetica',
    size:     20,
    anchor:   'middle',
    leading:  '1.5em'
})

text.draggable()
```

On chrome this problem does not happen.

Comment: `text-anchor="middle"` requires a different set of `drag()` algorithm. Same with `text-anchor="end"`. Try a different library like `snapsvg.js` as I find `svg.js` not too stable in the past.

Comment: thanks for the info about the anchor. For now I put the text element inside a group and I still can use anchor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This bug is fixed with version 2.1.3 of svg.draggable.js